# How is EGit used by Eclipse Developers

Tags: egit

I want to know how the eclipse developers use git ? Do they use the command line or do they use EGit plugin GUI ? If EGit GUI is used, then how do they manage it, since eclipse has one repository per plugin structure.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the getting started [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Getting_Started), then navigate through to answer your question.

Comment: I think my question was not clear. I want to know how the eclipse developers manage the eclipse structure of one repository per plugin. This could lead to a lot of issues particularly while fetching as changes could have been done in multiple plugins, then how will we tell the developer which plugins to checkout ? Moreover, while comitting also, after changes have been done to multiple plugins, we would have to individually commit each plugin separately, another increase in manual work.

Comment: hi @MritunjayaSharma reading thru this old question, wondered what structure you ended up using?